# Read form SqLITe Database and show in Textview [One By One]

Tags: android, android-sqlite, textview

I have this DatabaseCreator Java File.

## DatabseCreator

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseCreator extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH = "/GetInspiredAndHaveFun/assets/Jokes.db";
    private static String DB_NAME = "Jokes.db";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static String DATABASE_TABLE = "myjoke";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DataBaseCreator(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;

    }

    public void openDatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbe = checkDataBase();
        if (dbe) {
            Log.i("Tag", "dbe" + dbe);

        } else {
            Log.i("Tag", "dbdoesnotexist" + dbe);
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDataBase();

        }

    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream inp = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String ofn = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream oup = new FileOutputStream(ofn);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inp.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            oup.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        oup.flush();
        inp.close();
        oup.close();

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }

        catch (SQLiteException e) {

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
         
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    
}
```

Here's is where I want to access it's contents.

## myJokes Activity

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class Jokes extends Activity {
    {

        DataBaseCreator myDbHelper = new DataBaseCreator(this);
     myDbHelper = new DataBaseCreator(this);
        try{
            myDbHelper.copyDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    }
    }
```

I have an Instance of it in my Jokes.java file. How do I access the Jokes stored in the jokes and display it in a textview ( One by One ) Any Nice programmatic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first your Database should have any content. So add Columns to it. I’d suggest an `id` that `autoincrement` and maybe a `name` for the start.
You need to query at your database for it and iterate over the cursor.
A simple query would be just getting all Elements from the Database. It does look like this:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,allColumns, null, null, null, null,null);
```

It does return a cursor. It's a list and you can iterate over it with the `moveToNext()`. From every cursor you can get the values. So if you started querying you may look to reach the last id. First `cursor.moveToFirst()`. It does point to the First Element from the query. Now you can get values from the first row with the given cursor that points to it.
In the case you have the ID and the name you get the name from he first element of the query by `cursor.getString(1)`. The integer stands for the column you are getting from the row where your cursor is.

I hope it's comprehensible. My English isn't the best today. (please feel free to improve this!)
Small Iteration example

```
    String temp = "";
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        temp += curso.getString(1);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
```

Comment: and can I iterate that using i instead of an integer and increase i using a for loop? viz. cursor.getString(i) ??

Comment: Sure  you can loop that and get the elements in an. I add a small example

Comment: Sure :)
and How do I declare a Column inside the DataBaseCreator class?

Comment: Thanks for that. I have a column in my database named Jokes. How do I declare  it inside the DataBaseCreator clas?